# SQL query for parent-child chain

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, hierarchical-data

I have a single table that can refer to one other member in the table as a parent.  That parent could also refer to one other row as its parent...and so on.

```
id     col1     col2    parentID
1      foo      bar       NULL
2      blah     boo       1
3      fob      far       2
4      wob      lob       NULL
```

I would like to return the chain given an id.  So if the id were 3 I would return row 3, row 2 and row 1.  If id was 2 I would return row 2 and row 1.  If the id were 1 or 4 I would just return that row.

thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [recursive CTE](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml):

```
DECLARE @id INT
    SET @id = 3

;WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT t.id, t.parentid
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE t.id = @id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT x.id, x.parentid
   FROM YOUR_TABLE x
   JOIN hierarchy h ON h.parentid = x.id)
SELECT h.id
  FROM hierarchy h
```

Results:

```
id
---
3
2
1
```

Comment: Link don't work anymore, you can use [sqlservertutorial.net](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) for a nice example.

Answer (score 2):

IF you use a recursive CTE, don't forget to add

```
h.parentid <> x.id
```

on your join

```
JOIN hierarchy h ON h.parentid = x.id)
```

else you will just a *The maximum recursion*-error since it loops

Comment: Also you can use OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767) if you know you will hit a limit. See other answer with this included.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
SELECT P.cat_id AS parent_cat_id, P.parent_id AS ROOT, P.cat_name AS parent_cat_name, C.parent_id, C.cat_id, C.cat_name FROM categories AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN categories AS C ON C.parent_id=P.cat_id WHERE P.parent_id IS NULL ORDER BY parent_cat_name, cat_name
```

Comment: its koool :) ,such a nice query ,but I think its made for three level hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Hierarchy(ChildId, ChildName, Generation, ParentId)
AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, 0, ParentId
        FROM UserType AS FirtGeneration
        WHERE ParentId IS NULL        
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NextGeneration.Id, NextGeneration.Name, Parent.Generation + 1, Parent.ChildId

        FROM UserType AS NextGeneration
        INNER JOIN Hierarchy AS Parent ON NextGeneration.ParentId = Parent.ChildId    
)
SELECT *
    FROM Hierarchy
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Comment: Simple example using Parent-Child notation and Generations, I need to filter based on generations and the the Child-Parent notation makes the sections clear.