# Recursive function to show hierarchial display using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a table like this

```
ID               Title                    Parentid
1                Level1                    0
2                Level2                    1
3                Level3                    2 
4                Level4                    1
```

I want output in hierarchy model according to the parentid ,Id relationship as

- Level1
- ->Level2->Level 3
- -> Level4.

I am able to achieve like

```
                      level1
                        /\
                  level2  level4.
```

Here I am not getting level 3.
But i want the ouptut as shown in the first example using c#.

Comment: what DB ist his (Oracle...) ?

Comment: If you are using an RDBMS that supports recursive CTEs (such as SQLServer), you should be able to do this in SQL.

Comment: Oh..Thanks for the information. But my requirement is to do with c# only.Sql is used only to select data once.

Comment: @sachin: Can you explain why there is a requirement to do this in C#, rather than SQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query for parent-child chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188427/sql-query-for-parent-child-chain)

Comment: If you do want to do it in C#, for whatever reason, can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: @MarkBannister - Agreed.  It will be _much_ easier/cleaner to do sorting/root finding in SQL, and create nested entries from the result set.  Although I guess you could maintain an _additional_ `Dictionary` or something to be able to look up the parent based on it's `id` (supposing the entries were returned in order, of course).

Comment: @MarkBannister: Ok Mark, Could you please suggest me how it can be done with sql?

Comment: @sachin: See below - I haven't had a chance to test it, though.

Answer (score 1):

(Untested) Try:

```
;with RCTE as
(select id, title full_path from MyTable where ParentID = 0
 union all
 select m.id, r.full_path & '->' & m.title full_path
 from MyTable m, RCTE r
 where m.parentid = r.id)
select full_path from RCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all the parents defined before the children?

If so, you can use a **Dictionary(int, List(Item))**  (sorry about the parentheses, can't seem to get the angle brackets to work) where, say,

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public int ParentId { get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}


IDictionary<int, List<Item>> CreateTree(IEnumerable<Item> nodeList){

    var ret = new Dictionary<int, List<Item>>();

    foreach (var item in items) {

            if (!ret.ContainsKey(item.ParentId)) {
                ret.Add(item.ParentId, new List<Item>());
            }
            ret[item.ParentId].Add(item);
        }

    return ret;
}
```

This will give (for the above data)

0 => level1

1 => level2, level4

2 => level3

If the parent ids are not guaranteed to be before the child ids, then you need to add in some tweaking to allow for orphans and then add then process them at the end.

Hope this helps,

Alan.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion should be done inside of SQL Server using a Common Table Expression query (CTE).  One query should be able to give the results and the "levels" which can then be parsed in C# without the need for recursion in code.

Here's a link with examples:  (Mark's example also applies)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx