# Getting nodes under a given node?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, graph

Given a source node, I would like to get all nodes "under" it where under means that all nodes whose level is less than the given node's level and are reachable from the given node. I remember this can be done using common table expressions and am currently working on it. However, is there a way to do this fast on a large graph (consisting of about 100K nodes)?

**Sample data:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(Source VARCHAR(50), SourceLevel INT, Sink VARCHAR(50), SinkLevel INT);


INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 1, 'B', 2);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('A', 1, 'C', 2);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 2, 'C', 2);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 2, 'D', 3);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('B', 2, 'E', 3);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('C', 2, 'D', 3);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('C', 2, 'F', 3);
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('C', 2, 'G', 3);


SELECT *
FROM #TEMP

GO

DROP TABLE #TEMP
GO
```

**Graph:**

```
      A                        Level - 1
     / \
    B---C                      Level - 2
   / \ /|\
  E   D F G                    Level - 3
```

**Example:**

- Given B, I want to get: E,D
- Given A, I want to get: B,C,E,D,F,G
- Given C, I want to get: D,F,G

Comment: [check this.][1] this might answer your question


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188427/sql-query-for-parent-child-chain

Comment: @helloSuresh: Thanks! I had already started doing this through recursive CTEs and provided a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution here, using [Recursive CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) but there is still some problem with this (the answer does not exactly match yet but its getting there). I'll update this query once I get it close to my final requirement.

**EDIT 1**: The following satisfied all outputs except the one that asks for the root node 'A' in which case, it goes only one level deep for some reason.

**EDIT 2**: This gives the expected output. I'll check with other use cases now.

```
;WITH HIERARCHY AS (
  SELECT T.Source, T.SourceLevel, T.Sink, T.SinkLevel
    FROM #TEMP T
   WHERE T.Source = 'A'
   AND T.SourceLevel < T.SinkLevel
 UNION ALL
 SELECT X.Source, X.SourceLevel, X.Sink, X.SinkLevel
   FROM #TEMP X
   JOIN HIERARCHY H ON H.Sink = X.Source
)
SELECT DISTINCT H.Sink
  FROM HIERARCHY H
```