# How to get a Parent-Child record from different level in a same table in SSIS?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

Below are the details and output required.

The table has 3 columns:

1. Record
2. Parent Record
3. isactive

Output required as below based on inactive column:

e.g 1

```
Record  Parent_Record  Isactive
  1            0         1 
  2            1         0
  3            1         0
  4            2         0
  5            3         1
```

output

```
Record   Parent_Record   Isactive
    5           1            1
```

e.g 2

```
  Record  Parent_Record  Isactive
      1            0         0 
      2            1         0
      3            1         1
      4            2         0
      5            3         1
```

output

```
 Record   Parent_Record   Isactive
        5           3            1
```

Comment: You're probably going to need a recursive cte to get the parent record. This question should get you started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188427/sql-query-for-parent-child-chain

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to build the hierarchy starting from the leaf node going back to the higher active parent:

```
declare @tmp table (Record  int, Parent_Record  int, Isactive bit)
declare @recordToCheck int = 5

insert into @tmp values
 (1, 0, 1) 
,(2, 1, 0)
,(3, 1, 0)
,(4, 2, 0)
,(5, 3, 1)

;WITH RESULT (Record, Parent_Record, Isactive, Lev)
AS
(
    --anchor
    SELECT A.Record,Parent_Record, Isactive, 1 AS LEVEL
    FROM @tmp AS A 
    WHERE A.Record = @recordToCheck

    UNION ALL

    --outer
    SELECT C.Record, C.Parent_Record, C.Isactive, Lev + 1  
    FROM @tmp AS C
    INNER JOIN RESULT AS B 
    ON C.Record=B.Parent_Record
)
select top 1 @recordToCheck as Record, Record as Parent_Record, Isactive 
from RESULT 
where Isactive = 1 
order by lev desc
```

Result for e.g 1:

[image]

Result for e.g 2:

[image]